# Rate Limit Twitter API

Tags: twitter

I'm kind of confusion with twitter api guide on rate limiting mention over here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1

In their guide twitter has mention the follow field would be present in the response headers which can be use to a determine the amount of api call allowed , left and will rest at info

```
X-Rate-Limit-Limit: the rate limit ceiling for that given request
X-Rate-Limit-Remaining: the number of requests left for the 15 minute window
X-Rate-Limit-Reset: the remaining window before the rate limit resets in UTC epoch seconds
```

Now they have also given a rate limit status api to query against

```
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/application/rate_limit_status
```

Now I'm kind of confuse which of the above value should I follow to see how much api call is available for me before the desired limit is reach .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both seem to return the same. While [/get/application/rate_limit_status](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/application/rate_limit_status) is an API call which returns rate limits for all resources, X-rate-limits sets the header for the resource you just called.

Use [/get/application/rate_limit_status](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/application/rate_limit_status) to cache the no of API calls remaining, refresh at periodic intervals rather than having to make a call and then parse the header info to check if you've exceeded rate limits